# Missing certain overloaded SFML methods, while others are fine

Tags: c++, cmake, build, sfml

Im trying to build an application on SFML and decided to build it myself instead of using apt package manager. Im also using cmake but i don't think that matters much for my question:

In my file UserInterface.h i have #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
which worked fine before when i used SFML-dev from apt.
Compiler tells that a lot of SFML methods that take in (int x, int y) does not exist (while finding the version taking in sf::Vector2f). These overloaded methods worked fine before.

Now i looked into the [source code](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Transformable.cpp) of SFML and can't actually find the overloaded functions? even though they are in the [Documentation:](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a56c67bd80aae8418d13fb96c034d25ec)

```
void sf::Transformable::setOrigin(float x, float y)
```

I don't understand where i went wrong.
The rest of SFML seems to be fine. How does SFML even support these overloaded methods if they are not declared?

This is the output i get when building:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::RectangleShape::setOrigin(int, int)’
  103 |     background.setOrigin(0, 0);
      |                              ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics/Shape.hpp:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:34,
                 from /home/bonkt/dev/digitus/src/UserInterface/UserInterface.h:1,
                 from /home/bonkt/dev/digitus/src/UserInterface/UserInterface.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp:115:10: note: candidate: ‘void sf::Transformable::setOrigin(const Vector2f&)’
  115 |     void setOrigin(const Vector2f& origin);
```

edit:
When casting the arguments (int) to float it won't work, so that's not the problem. It also occurs for many other similar methods:
window.setPosition()
window.setScale()

sf::FloatRect()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my answer: The apt SFML package i used earlier must have been an older version of SFML.
I found [these](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/2055) merged pull requests at their github just a couple of weeks ago. SFML decided that numerical pairs are not needed, as usage of sf::Vector2T is more consistent with the rest of the API. - So i'll just change my code to use SF::Vector2f

I just had really unlucky timing as the new pullrequests was merged just 5 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

The master branch of the SFML repository is the current work-in-progress version 3 of SFML whereas the [latest official release](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php) (at this time) is [2.5.1](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/).

[The documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/learn.php) is for the latest release and that still uses the separate (x, y) for parameters. The 2.6.x version (although not released yet) should follow almost the same documentation without many 'breaking' changes.

SFML 3 will introduce breaking changes (from SFML 2 versions) and uses (will use) `sf::Vector2<t>` for its xy pair but, since it hasn't officially been released yet (anything can still change), there is no official documentation on SFML's site for this as of yet.

With that said, if you generate the documentation yourself from the source code, it should be up-to-date.